# Linq Select statement inside Order By

Tags: sql, linq, select, sql-order-by

Is it possible to write an linq select inside order by something like :

```
 ReservationDTO obj = new ReservationDTO();
 obj.bookroomview = obj.bookroomview.GroupBy(a => a.RoomFloor)
                .Select(a => obj.bookroomview
                    .Select(x => new { Amount = a.Select(b => b.ReservationRoomID).Count(), Name = a.Key })
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Amount)

                ).ToList().AsQueryable();
```

My aim is to select all obj.roombookview items but sort them according to Count calculation. If it is possible how can i write it?

My view class :

```
public partial class Book_Room_View
{
    public Nullable<int> ReservationID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ReservationRoomID { get; set; }        
    public string RoomName { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Hi, what is the type of ReservationRoomID, is it collection ? 
maybe if you add your bookroomview class, it would be easier for us to help you.

Comment: Hi, i added view class in my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you were to order the groups by reservations, I guess this is the proper way doing it, you don't need to count specific attribute as I guess you are trying, just order by the count of the value list.

```
obj.bookroomview.GroupBy(a => a.RoomFloor)
                .OrderBy(gr => gr.Count())
                .Select(gr => new { Amount = gr.Count(), Name = gr.Key })
                .AsQueryable();
```

Comment: It gives me an error `CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<<anonymous type: int Amount, int? Name>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ReservationSystem.Models.Book_Room_View>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) ReservationSystem`

Comment: yes because it is different type, we already casted the list to an anonymous type right, here `Select(gr => new { Amount = gr.Count(), Name = gr.Key }` 
you need to assign this to a new variable, or you need to cast this to list of ReservationSystem.Models.Bo‌​ok_Room_View.

Comment: If i assign this to a new variable(`var query = obj.bookroomview.....`) how can i reach all items (RoomName, Satartdate...) using query? (Sorry i m beginner)

Comment: it depends on what you are using, you can create a new type and select it, or you can select they list which makes no sense because the grouping then would be for nothing, I would remove the select statement, and assign this to a new variable, you will have dictionary key, List, for each key (room floor) you will have list of bookroomview, which you can loop through or what ever you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your helps